# How to add conditional inside Linq Aggregate in C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq, oop

I'm trying Linq over Imperative style, but I can't convert this conditional inside Aggregate to Linq.

Consider two following examples.

**Simple example:**

```
public enum Color {
    Red,  // Red score = 10
    Yellow,  // Yellow score = 5
    Green,  // Green score = 2
}

//Populate our sample list
public List<Color> Colors = new List<Color> {Red, Green, Green, Yellow};

//I need help on this one
public float Score => Colors.Aggregate(0.0f, (total, next) => 
{
    //How to properly use conditional inside Aggregate?
    if (next == Color.Red) {
        return total + 10.0f;
    } else if (next == Color.Yellow) {
        return total + 5.0f;
    } else if (next == Color.Green) {
        return total + 2.0f;
    }
    //edit: forgot the default
    return total;
}



Log(Score); //19
```

Edit: I have tried moving the conditional to Select, but then it will just move the problem, Which is how to add conditional inside Linq Select?

```
public float Score => Colors.Select(x => 
{
    // The problem still happening
    if (x == Color.Red) {
        return 10.0f;
    } else if (x == Color.Yellow) {
        return 5.0f;
    } else if (x == Color.Green) {
        return 2.0f;
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
.Aggregate(0.0f, (total, next) => total + next);
```

And here is the **complex example**, basically it's just a stat modifier for a game,

```
// This is a Game Status Modifier, for example: "Strength 30 + 10%"
public enum StatModType
{
    Flat = 100, // Flat addition to Stat
    PercentAdd = 200, // Percent addition to Stat
    ... // many other type of addition
}

private float _baseValue = 30.0f;

public List<StatModifier> StatModifiers = new List<StatModifier>
{...} //dummy data

public float Value => StatModifiers.Aggregate(_baseValue, (finalValue, mod) =>
{
    //I need help on this one
    if (mod.Type == StatModType.Flat)
        return finalValue + mod.Value;
    else if (mod.Type == StatModType.PercentAdd)
    // When we encounter a "PercentAdd" modifier
        return finalValue + finalValue * mod.Value;
    else if (mod.Type == ...)
        //and continues below everytime I add more modifier types..
}


Log(Value); // Strength = 33;
```

Edit: I'll just post (Credit: https://forum.unity.com/threads/tutorial-character-stats-aka-attributes-system.504095/) the imperative code in case someone needs it, I also have a hard time reading this one:

```
private float CalculateFinalValue()
{
    float finalValue = BaseValue;
    float sumPercentAdd = 0; // This will hold the sum of our "PercentAdd" modifiers

    for (int i = 0; i < statModifiers.Count; i++)
    {
        StatModifier mod = statModifiers[i];

        if (mod.Type == StatModType.Flat)
        {
            finalValue += mod.Value;
        }
        else if (mod.Type == StatModType.PercentAdd) // When we encounter a "PercentAdd" modifier
        {
            sumPercentAdd += mod.Value; // Start adding together all modifiers of this type

            // If we're at the end of the list OR the next modifer isn't of this type
            if (i + 1 >= statModifiers.Count || statModifiers[i + 1].Type != StatModType.PercentAdd)
            {
                finalValue *= 1 + sumPercentAdd; // Multiply the sum with the "finalValue", like we do for "PercentMult" modifiers
                sumPercentAdd = 0; // Reset the sum back to 0
            }
        }
        else if (mod.Type == StatModType.PercentMult) // Percent renamed to PercentMult
        {
            finalValue *= 1 + mod.Value;
        }
    }

    return (float)Math.Round(finalValue, 4);
}
```

How can I add conditional inside Aggregate / Reduce / Scan function?

Comment: The method that filters is `Where`, not `Aggregate`. If you want to generate different values, ie project, use `Select`. `Aggregate` is meant to aggregate the data, not do the job of the other operators

Comment: Aggregate produces a value for all records, it can't skip or filter them. It will have to return the accumulator value unmodified for any values it doesn't like.

Comment: Hello, so should I just move the if..else problem to `Select` before using `Aggregate`? There will pose another question, how to add conditional inside `Select` .. I can't use `Where` because all data is needed.

Comment: If you can yes. If you need to apply different operations for different records though, a) you have a rather weird implementation that's susceptible to order changes and b) you should return the accumulator, ie `finalValue`, unmodified `return finalValue;`. You'll get a different result if you switch the order of `Flat` and `PercentAdd`

Comment: You just need to return the unchanged accumulator by default. (the last else case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *extracting model* in both cases i.e.

**Simple Example:**

```
private static Dictionary<Color, float> s_ColorScores = new Dictionary<Color, float>() {
  {Color.Red,   10.0f},
  {Color.Yellow, 5.0f},
  {Color.Green,  2.0f},
};

...

float Score = Colors
  .Sum(color => s_ColorScores[color]);
```

**Complex Example:**

```
private static Dictionary<StatModType, Func<float, float, float>> s_Modifications = new 
  Dictionary<StatModType, Func<float, float, float>> {
    {StatModType.Flat,       (prior, value) => prior + value},
    {StatModType.PercentAdd, (prior, value) => prior + prior * value},
     //TODO: add modification rules here
  };

public float Value => StatModifiers
  .Aggregate(_baseValue, (prior, mod) => s_Modifications[mod.Type](prior, mod.Value));
```

So you are going to have game's *model* (`s_ColorScores`, `s_Modifications`...) with rules, settings, balances etc. (which you will probably want to *tune*, may be `Color.Yellow` score of `6.0f` is a better choice) separated from simple *business logics*.

Comment: Oh nice use of Sum , Thank you I learnt more of Linq, I was thinking to make every enum its own class with one method that can be called in `Select`, but that will over-complicate things. Dictionary like this could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the behaviors associated to the enum types are static and not dynamic, based on [this MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) article another approach would be to use enumeration classes instead of enum types. To simplify this, you could use the [`SmartEnum` package](https://github.com/ardalis/SmartEnum).

Using this lib and approach, your use cases turn into:

**Simple Example:**

```
public sealed class Color: SmartEnum<Color>
{
    public static readonly Color Red = new Color (nameof(Red), 1, 10.0f);
    public static readonly Color Yellow = new Color (nameof(Yellow), 2, 20.0f);
    public static readonly Color Green = new Color (nameof(Green), 3, 30.0f);

    private Color(string name, int value, double score) 
      : base(name, value)
    {
      this.Score = score;
    }

    public float Score {get;}
}

float TotalScore = Colors
  .Sum(color => color.Score);
```

**Complex Example:**

```
public sealed class StatMod: SmartEnum<StatMod>
{
    public static readonly StatMod FlatAdd = new StatMod(nameof(FlatAdd), 200, (prev, val)=>prev+val);
    public static readonly StatMod PercentAdd = new StatMod(nameof(PercentAdd), 300, (prev,val)=>prior + prior * value);

    private StatMod(string name, int value, Func<float, float, float> reduce) : base(name, value)
    {
      this.Reduce = reduce;
    }

    public Func<float, float, float> Reduce {get;}
}

public float Value => StatModifiers
  .Aggregate(_baseValue, (prior, mod) => mod.Reduce(prev, mod.Value));
```